# Conexão TCP Servidor (127.0.0.1) Porque esta travando nesta linha?

Tags: c#

Estou tentando criar um chat com cliente e servidor em c#, mas estou tendo problema nesta linha:

```
client = servidor.AcceptTcpClient(); //Espera conexão
```

Vou postar meu código aqui pra vê se algum de vocês consegue descobrir o erro que está fazendo ele trava.

```
private void Servidor() {
    ip = textBox1.Text;
    servidor = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port); //Cria endpoint com ip e porta
    servidor.Start();
    richTextBox1.Text = "[Servidor] Esperando conexão...";
    client = servidor.AcceptTcpClient(); //Espera conexão
    richTextBox1.Text += "\n[Servidor] Client conectado!";
    Recebendo();
}

void Button1Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Servidor();
}
private void Recebendo() {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[256]; //Buffer para a trânsferência de mensagens
        int count;
        while(true) {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); //Pega stream do client
            while((count = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0) //recebe até‚ que não existam mais bytes para ler
            {
                mensagemEntrada = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, count); //converte os bytes recebidos do buffer em uma string
                richTextBox1.Text += "\n[Client] " + mensagemEntrada;
            }
        }
    } catch(System.Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    public void Desconectar() {
        client.Close(); //fecha conexão
        servidor.Stop(); // para de escutar conexões
        richTextBox1.Text += "Conexão encerrada!";
    }
```

Comment: Se você quiser que não trave, terá que usar uma função `async`.

Answer (score 1):

Não há nada de errado. A linha `client = servidor.AcceptTcpClient();` bloqueia até que você receba alguma conexão. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

Servidor

```
class Servidor {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string ip = "127.0.0.1";
        var porta = 13000;
        var servidor = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), porta);
        servidor.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Aguardando conexão...");
        using (var cliente = servidor.AcceptTcpClient()) {
            var streamEntrada = cliente.GetStream();
            var buffer = new byte[cliente.ReceiveBufferSize];
            var bytesLidos = streamEntrada.Read(buffer, 0, cliente.ReceiveBufferSize);
            var dadosRecebidos = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesLidos);

            Console.WriteLine($"Mensagem recebida: {dadosRecebidos}");
        }
        servidor.Stop();
    }
}
```

Cliente

```
class Cliente {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var ip = "127.0.0.1";
        var port = 13000;
        using (var cliente = new TcpClient()) {
            cliente.Connect(ip, port);
            if (cliente.Connected) {
                var streamSaida = cliente.GetStream();
                var bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit");
                streamSaida.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
                cliente.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Execute primeiro o Servidor e depois o Cliente e verá a mensagem sendo enviada de um para o outro. Repare que somente após a conexão do Cliente é que a linha `var cliente = servidor.AcceptTcpClient()`é desbloqueada.

Para recepção constante de dados vindos do cliente, é necessário colocar o código que recebe as conexões em um laço `while`.

Tomei a liberdade de alterar algumas trechos no código.

Fonte:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx